# Were the other Babylon stations less technologically advanced compared to Babylon 5?

Tags: babylon-5

Since Babylon 5 was the last one to be built and we are at least certain the Babylons 4 and 5 *look* different, are there canonical explanations for any technology differences between the various stations?

Comment: Based on the fact that they were using the same targeting scanners on B5/her Star Fury squadrons as they did during the war 10 years prior, I think that any technological differences would be minor. In fact, most of what we see during the Mimbari War looks the same as we see in B5. Only new thing we see are the 2 man Star Furies

Comment: By running a complex machine-learning algorithm, I've estimated that Babylon 5 was about 25% more technologically advanced than Babylon 4.

Comment: Babylon 4 had more features - it was almost a ship as it had enough thrusters to make it mobile.  But that's more budget in-universe than advanced technology.  B5 was just budget scraps and the Minbari covering some costs after the Earth Alliance burned through the cost of the first 3 partial stations and one titanic finished one that mysteriously disappeared.

Comment: @Daishozen --- I think Omega class destroyers were introduced after the Earth-Minbari war.

Comment: It may be worth noting that B5 was constructed in 2 years. Presumably most of it was prefabricated and transported to the epsilon system. Honestly this is a large world building gap as we never see moon or asteroid mining. Though it is definitely not relevant to the story either.  (I'm forever grateful for the conscious avoidance of technobabble)  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/when-was-babylon-5-constructed-and-how-long-did-it-take?rq=1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Money.**

After getting B4 mostly complete and nearly operational, only to have it vanish, Earth Alliance was on the verge of giving up.

It was only after an offer of support from the Minbari (which they used to veto commanders not named Jeffery Sinclair) that construction on B5 began - and its design is noticeably trimmed.  B4 had two separate rotating sections to simulate different gravities, as well as engines that would allow it to be mobile in emergencies.  Neither feature made it to B5.

Quote from the creator:

> B5 is smaller than B4 because they sunk most of their budget into B4; on B5 they had to get outside funding, and scrimped.